# How to resolve this error: LLVM ERROR: Error parsing inline asm

Tags: c, linux, kernel, clang, llvm

I am getting the following error during build process:

```
CC hal/mmu.o
<inline asm>:1:2: error: instruction requires: armv6t2
        WFI
        ^
LLVM ERROR: Error parsing inline asm

{standard input}: Assembler messages:
{standard input}: Warning: end of file not at end of a line; newline inserted
{standard input}:588: Error: missing expression -- `bl'
{standard input}: Error: open CFI at the end of file; missing .cfi_endproc directive
Makefile:115: recipe for target 'hal/mmu.o' failed
make[1]: *** [hal/mmu.o] Error 1
```

How to resolve the above error ?

Comment: I'm guessing your processor doesn't support the instruction you are trying to use.

Comment: Thanks. But don't you think processor is immaterial here. After all I am not running the built code on processor, I am only compiling it. It may also happen that I maybe compiling for a different processor (cross-compilation). I think its related to compiler issue rather than processor. Isn't it?

Comment: The code contains inline assembly. This is code written in assembly language for a specific processor, not code written in C (which is generic and portable). Therefore, the program can only be compiled for that specific processor.